# Page_LoadComplete not working on master page (C#)

Tags: c#, events, master-pages

i'm trying to hide/show some control on a page from Page_LoadComplete.  If a put the code in any page, it works OK, but when I put the code on the master page, it doesn't work.  I've used debug and that code is not executed in the master page.  I've checked the AutoEventWireup=true on the @Master but i'm guessing if that event only applies for Pages and not for Masters.

I need it to be in the Page_LoadComplete because the visibility depends on a button click, so I can't use Page_Load event.

Thanks.

Comment: We need to see the code - without this, we cannot help you. We need to see **what** you are doing and **how** you are doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MasterPage does not have a LoadComplete event.  Only the Page.  [This is a comprehensive list of all events.](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/03/08/asp-net-page-events-lifecycle.aspx)